# WP7 : Grid DataTemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Grid of images, images are dynamically added to the grid.

How can i create a cell dataTemplate for this Grid to add border radius to each image?

Comment: What kind of grid are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a cell template for the grid, but you can definetly add a default style to your image, so that the image comes with a border and you just place it in the grid. 
Just another way to think about your problem.